# Code contract ensures not proven for loop

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I'm just starting to play around with .Net Code Contracts (in VS2010 Ultimate .Net 4), to try to get an idea of what the static checker can and can't prove.

I'm trying to following example :-

```
public int Mult(int num1, int num2)
    {
        Contract.Requires(num2 >= 0);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() == (num1 * num2));
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++)
        {
            result = result + num1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

ie, a simple implementation of a multiply function, by repeated adding.

The static checker can't verify that the postcondition is met :-

```
CodeContracts: ensures unproven: Contract.Result<int>() == (num1 * num2)
```

Is my function not actually computing the product correctly.. or is there another reason why the static checker can't verify the Requires ? Does the presence of a loop cause it difficulty ?

If it's difficult for the static checker to verify things when loops are present, I can imagine it would get quite annoying to have a lot of warnings all the time.

I don't like the option of putting in Assumes to tell it what I think is going on, because it's generally my invalid assumptions that are the cause of bugs in the first place !

So, when the static checker can't prove something, how can we go about helping it ?
For example, I could rewrite the function as a recursive function - would the checker then be able to verify it more easily ? (And advocates of functional programming might say this is how it should be written in the first place - no changing state etc !). What other ways can I change my code to make it easier for the static checker ?

Thanks !:)

Comment: Here is information that is kinda related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/reachability/

Comment: @Jeffrey, by chance I ended up linking to the same blog posts as you did. Interesting! :)

Answer (score 1):

The static checker will never be able to prove this, but the run-time checker will.

The static checker is applied at compile-time. In order to be able to prove your Ensures, it would have to be able to fully analyze your algorithm and what you're doing. It is not that powerful.

The run-time checker will of course validate the Ensures every time your function exits, and with proper unit-testing, that should prove the validity of the Ensures.